# Can I have a string object store its data within the structure?

Tags: vb.net, c++-cli

I'm looking for a quick way to serialize custom structures consisting of basic value types and strings.

Using C++CLI to pin the pointer of the structure instance and destination array and then memcpy the data over is working quite well for all the value types. However, if I include any reference types such as string then all I get is the reference address.

Expected as much since otherwise it would be impossible for the structure to have a fixed.. structure. I figured that maybe, if I make the string fixed size, it might place it inside the structure though. Adding < VBFixedString(256) > to the string declaration did not achieve that.

Is there anything else that would place the actual data inside the structure?

Comment: What "structure" (i.e. you don't show us). If you are trying to copy data from a .Net type to a C++ structure, then at least for `String^` you need to marshal to a `std::string`, `CString`, or C style string. You can't memcopy.

Comment: structure is a keyword in vb.net. If i start marshaling stuff i'd have to rely on reflection which is not good for speed at all. Call me crazy but a fixed size char array ought to be possible

Comment: You can use Marshal::StructureToPtr() if you don't want to take care of it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pinning a managed object and memcpy-ing the content will never give you what you want. Any managed object, be it `String`, a character array, or anything else will show up as a reference, and you'll just get a memory location.

If I read between the lines, it sounds like you need to call some C or C++ (not C++/CLI) code, and pass it a C struct that looks similar to this:

```
struct UnmanagedFoo
{
    int a_number;
    char a_string[256];
};
```

If that's the case, then I'd solve this by setting up the automatic marshaling to handle this for you. Here's how you'd define that struct so that it marshals properly. (I'm using C# syntax here, but it should be an easy conversion to VB.net syntax.)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct ManagedFoo
{
    public int a_number;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=256)]
    public string a_string;
}
```

Explanation:

- [`StructLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx)[`(LayoutKind.Sequential)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx) specifies that the fields should be in the declared order. The default LayoutKind, `Auto`, allows the fields to be re-ordered if the compiler wants.
- [`CharSet=CharSet.Ansi`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.charset.aspx) specifies the type of strings to marshal. You can specify [`CharSet.Ansi`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.charset.aspx) to get `char` strings on the C++ side, or [`CharSet.Unicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.charset.aspx) to get `wchar_t` strings in C++.
- [`MarshalAs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx)[`(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) specifies a string inline to the struct, which is what you were asking about. There are several other string types, with different semantics, see the [`UnmanagedType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) page on MSDN for descriptions.
- [`SizeConst=256`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeconst.aspx) specifies the size of the character array. Note that this specifies the number of characters (or when doing arrays, number of array elements), *not* the number of bytes.

Now, these marshal attributes are an instruction to the built-in marshaler in .Net, which you can call directly from your VB.Net code. To use it, call [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zhzfk83.aspx) to go from the .Net object to unmanaged memory, and [`Marshal.PtrToStructure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx) to go from unmanaged memory to a .Net object. MSDN has some good examples of calling those two methods, take a look at the linked pages.

**Wait, what about C++/CLI?** Yes, you could use C++/CLI to marshal from the .Net object to a C struct. If your structs get too complex to represent with the `MarshalAs` attribute, it's highly appropriate to do that. In that case, here's what you do: Declare your .Net struct like I listed above, without the `MarshalAs` or `StructLayout`. Also declare the C struct, plain and ordinary, also as listed above. When you need to switch from one to the other, copy things *field by field*, not a big memcpy. Yes, all the fields that are basic types (integers, doubles, etc.) will be a repetitive `output.a_number = input.a_number`, but that's the proper way to do it.